# jQuery: only direct descendant selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following structure :

```
<ul>
    <li><a>link</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>link</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>link</a></li>
                    <li><a>link</a></li>
                    <li><a>link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a>link</a>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a>link</a></li>
                    <li><a>link</a></li>
                    <li><a>link</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>content 
            <ul>
                <li><a>link</a></li>
                <li><a>link</a></li>
                <li><a>link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
    </li>
    <li><a>link</a></li>
    <li><a>link</a></li>
    <li><a>link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I wanna select only the anchors that fall directly under the `<li>` tags ( children) but not the ones that fall under other tags (grandchildren)
if i do

```
$('ul li> a')
```

I will also get the the ul which is nested under the div. is there a "clean" way to do this?
thank you

ps: I would like to have a generic selector ( this is for a menu pluggin so I want it to ignore all the anchor tags that don't fall directly in the flow of a menu)

Comment: Can you add an id to the root `ul` to distinguish it from any `ul`? Then `$('#root > li > a')` won't grab that deeper `ul > li > a`. Or do you also want the other deep `ul > li > a`s to be captured, just not the one under the `div`?

Comment: yeah, that is a possibility however I want to use this in a pluggin so the selector has to be less strict.

Comment: So you want to grab all `a` elements at any depth so long as their ancestors are only `ul` or `li`? So, `ul > li > a` would match, and a `ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a` would match too?

Comment: yes but in that case ul>li>div>ul>li>a would also match wouldn't it?

Comment: That's what I'm asking about. Ideally, it _shouldn't_ match if a `div` (or anything other than `ul` or `li`) is in there, right?

Comment: @wiseguy, yes exactly ...it should not match anything UNDER a div (or anything other than ul or li)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The Final Solution

This answer has been completely re-edited to keep it updated. The final solution is basically a selector, where starting from the original `<ul>` element's ID, select all anchors within the list items that doesn't break the menu structure's flow. That is, if there is an element other than `<ul>` or `<li>` nested within, don't select anything within those elements, even if there is a menu within.

The resulting selector (`#root` is the ID of the main `<ul>`) :

```
$('#root > li > a, #root ul:not(#root :not(ul,li) ul) > li > a')
```

You can try a demo over here: http://jsfiddle.net/9gPzQ/31/

However the original poster **@salmane** wanted to do it for a plugin, which already comes with an element passed in, so he came up with the following code to do the same as above, but within already selected objects passed as selector context:

```
$('li >a',this.content).not($(':not(ul,li) a',this.content))
```

### Other interesting selectors

Along the way of finding a solution, certain interesting selectors came up due to my misunderstanding of the problem, but I'll include them here anyway just for the record, it might come in handy for some. :)

This selector selects the anchors of list items that are on the top level of a menu, wherever they are on the page:

```
$(':not(li) > ul > li > a')
```

This selector selects the anchors of list items that are on the top level of a menu, ignoring menus that are nested within other menus, even if they are nested within other containers:

```
$('ul:not(ul ul) > li > a')
```

You can try these to selector in a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9gPzQ/4/

Comment: +1 Nice solution. The performance should be OK, since selection generally works right-to-left, so there's no need for an expensive `*` call anywhere.

Comment: actually that sounds close but something that would select only the ul>li>a that fall directly under an li ..your suggestion does exactly the opposite, or am i wrong?

Comment: so I guess that work if I do : ('li > a').not(':not(li) > ul > li > a')...I should try... @lonesomeday i hope your assessment about performance still holds :)

Comment: It selects `ul > li > a` only if the `ul` is not a direct parent of an `li`. It will still select the ones within the `<div>` though...

Comment: Exactly. You have to have some easily identifiable root element to base the entire selector off of.

Comment: after testing....it works..BUT...it selects elements that fit that criteria under the div...not sure how to explain this. but ideally I would like the query to ignore the content of the div all together...so far this does not do it.

Comment: @DarthJDG, I have tried that but no success. could you please explain to me what this part "ul:not(ul ul)" means? thank you

Comment: That means select all `<ul>`s which are not nested in other `<ul>`s, it even filters if there is a `<div>` in between, like in your example. Did you check my fiddle? Just look at the green ones, is that not what you want to select?

Comment: @salmane: Check out my updated fiddle, I numbered all links. Which ones do you want selected? http://jsfiddle.net/9gPzQ/4/

Comment: @DarthJDG I just did. Almost ...it should select them all except 10 11 and 12 and any others that might be nested in the DIV . thank you so much ..great work so far !

Comment: @darthJDG here is what I could come up with though by not mean this is pretty :) var non = $('#menu :not(li) > ul');
non= $(non).find('ul').andSelf();
$('ul').not(non)    Do you know of a better way to write this by any chance? thank you

Comment: @darthJDG I forgot to mention that i named the parent Ul #menu :)

Comment: @salmane: I've got something that could be used, but it needs a root element to wrap the whole thing in. But from there, it rejects everything not part of the menu flow: http://jsfiddle.net/9gPzQ/28/ I could not do it from `root2`, the main `<ul>` yet.

Comment: Without doubt your method is much more elegant. and as ugly as my method is, i would have to choose it because the plugging would call the parent UL in this way $('#menu').menu_pluggin(). Anyway you could help me rewrite my method in a better way?

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/9gPzQ/30/ It doesn't need a container now, `#root2` is the ID of the main `<ul>`, it selects direct >li>a first, then does the magic that's above. ;)

Comment: Sweet!! You Rock!! :) It was a fun one! :)

Comment: @darthJDG how would write that if you had an object called : this.menu as opposed to #root2?

Comment: It took a little fiddling around but this is what it looks like using an object : $('li >a',this.content).not($(':not(ul,li) a',this.content)) Thanks again @DarthJDG for your help :)

Comment: That's a nice solution indeed. That was fun.

Comment: Just for the record, I have updater my answer to contain the final solutions and all failed attempts due to my misunderstanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
$('ul:parent ul li>a')
```

This will give you all the `li>a`'s without the div or anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Great input of @DarthJDG

this is the solution

```
$('li >a',this.content).not($(':not(ul,li) a',this.content))
```

this.content being the object referenced by the plugging in this case the object is the parent UL

I hope this helps someone