# jquery ui accordion opens all children ul

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a series of nested ul that contain my menu data. I wish to use an accordion that displays the child ul when click.  My issue is that when the item is click all of the child ul open.

here is the js fiddle.  See how all children open.

http://jsfiddle.net/VD5Mk/

here is how i call the accordion

```
 $("#main-nav").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
```

and here is the list

```
<ul id="main-nav">
<li> item one
    <ul>
        <li> item one
            <ul>
                <li> item one </li>
                <li> item two </li>
                <li> item three </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li> item two </li>
        <li> item three </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li> item two </li>
<li> item three </li>
```

Comment: Please create a js fiddle with the issue.

Comment: ok. http://jsfiddle.net/VD5Mk/

Comment: Work with this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064198/jquery-only-direct-descendant-selector